# Why won't this image resize code work on my PHP site?

Tags: php, image, apache, image-resizing

Here is the code in "test.php" at the `root` of my site. I am trying to take an image from the `pin` directory and resize and save it into `root`.

```
$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage('/pin/PD101822-front.jpg');    
$thumb->resizeImage(100,100,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('/abc.jpg');
$thumb->clear();
$thumb->destroy();
```

What am I doing wrong?

This does say that Imagick is turned on for my server:

```
if( class_exists("Imagick") )
{
    echo 'installed';
}
```

Comment: root of site vs root of server

Comment: Check if the root map has writing privileges

Comment: Try using relative paths, i.e. 'pin/PD101822-front.jpg' and 'abc.jpg' (without the starting slash)